# Increasing the size of all content

Tags: ios, ipad, accessibility, ipados

I'm looking for something that works like "display size" on Android, "change the size of text, apps, and other items" on Windows or "zoom level" on Linux Mint.

"Text size" doesn't cut it because it leaves a lot of things unscaled and accessibility zoom - well, I'm sure it's nice for severely impaired people but I just want to scale up everything by something like 25 to 50% without having to need to pan around.

(I'm using an iPad Pro with iOS 14.4.2)

Answer (score 1):

I use iOS 14.4.1 and the same/similar iPad and I can say: there is no official way for force zooming. Things you can use to have a similar effect:

- **Fullscreen zoom** in Accessibility settings you can modify zoom and for example - make it fullscreen or control with keyboard, but there is only one thing you need to remember to double-tap screen with 3 fingers and move zoom with also 3 fingers (because "normal" scroll acts normally as without zoom ). I won’t share the screenshot here because zoom resizes that to size the same as without it.
- **Resize font** (only in Accessibility settings and in shortcuts) to make font size up to about 1000 times bigger than normal and it resizes also icons, (I just saw that when moving this font-slider in setting and watching icons of setting’s tabs).  It’s named "enable bigger fonts" and should be over this place where you choose font size - [**Settings** ▶ **Accessibility**▶ **Display and Text Size** "Bold Text", "Larger Text"] here is the maximum size of text (and even other things) by enabling that:
  [image]

You can also bold text if you want in the category above text size.

BTW, you can force that but then it’d really be hard and then you’ll need to modify iOS.

Answer (score 0):

On your iPad go to settings. From settings go to Display and Brightness. Go to the page on the right and move to bottom of page. There you will see View. Tap on that header and you'll get a page called Display Zoom. Select if you want Standard or Zoomed display. After checking Zoomed hit the set button. You may have to restart ipad. This increases size of the displayed items but i don't know if its 20% or not. There may be other ways to fine tune this but I don't know how.